# Local H2 Server-Client connection with DB running in memory

Tags: java, database-connection, h2

I have two independent Java apps which I would like to communicate with each other through an in-memory H2-DB.  In theory very straight forward, but I cannot get the connection to work.

What I am trying to do:
I create an in-memory DB executing `jdbc:h2:mem:test`.
With the client(s), I try connecting to it.  I tried `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test` and similar connection strings, but all without success.

Is it possible to connect to an in-memory DB?  What should the connection strings look like to make this work?  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a ton of reading and trial-and-error with H2 options (http://h2database.com/html/features.html and http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html), I found that it is possible to access an in-memory database from multiple processes on the same machine (or remotely) using TCP/IP or SSL/TLS.  The connection string for an in-memory database `test` is `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:test`.

Answer (score 0):

H2 database can be shared but not in memory, Your may please refer to official documentation:

http://h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode

First application with open it in embedded mode and other application will use server mode.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  I actually found that it is possible to access an in-memory database from multiple processes on the same machine (cf. my answer).  I am awarding the 50 point bounty to you for taking the time.  :-)