# Flyway start with version 1 if using H2 in memory DB

Tags: h2, flyway

Using Flyway 4.0.1 H2 1.3 baselineOnMigrate=true. When i use H2:mem, flyway start with version 1 in his metadata table. It should start with empty version. When i use disk DB this is not heppening. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It is because DB is accessed from diferent classloaders. Every classloader has its own DB. I need to use TCP connection. Details on: [Local H2 Server-Client connection with DB running in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36322196/local-h2-server-client-connection-with-db-running-in-memory)